# What is the typeof for a XML object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I know JSON and plain text but I don't know the exact `typeof` for XML since I couldn't find a test link. I'm presuming it's an `object` since HTML DOM access uses it but I just need to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Without a code snippet to go on, you might be getting back an "XMLDocument" type (depending on the script engine).

I tried this out/verified using Chrome:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://localhost/Test/Test' })
  .done(function(f) { 
     console.log(f instanceof XMLDocument ? "XMLDocument" : "object");
  });
```

where my simple Test/Test returned an XML string with MIME type text/xml:

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return Content("<test><answer accurate=\"true\">42</answer></test>", "text/xml");
    }
```

Comment: I've completely forgot about this issue. However, this answer is using Ajax itself which defeats the purpose making my own. Sorry, but the help was appreciated though.

Comment: Neither your question nor your response make sense to me, then.  It sounds like you're documenting a library and have either a variable, parameter, or return type of XMLDocument.  I only included some code to show I tested the Javascript type returned by the runtime.

Comment: I apologize about that, my fault. I've updated the question. I just realized I had 2 things mixed up in the question before.